# SailsJS / Vue / Node: variable undefined when sending to an EJS page

Tags: node.js, sails.js, ejs

This is a bit of a strange one and I think it's a basic syntax error, but I cannot seem to pin it down.

I have successfully got my controller in Sails (NodeJS) sending some JSON through to the view (an EJS file). It's an object called "Profile" (pulled from a DB, which I have connected & working).

The JSON my page is receiving looks like this:

```
[{
"personal_photo_url": "bing.jpg",
"show_profile": false,
"id": 1
}]
```

The relevant code snippet on my .ejs file (view) looks like this:

```
<h3>Personal photo: {{profile.personal_photo_url}}</h3>  
<h3>Show profile to others?: {{ profile.show_profile }}</h3>
<h3>User ID:{{ profile }}</h3>
```

When the page loads, I'm not seeing any text against "welcome sound" or the "show profile to others?" line, however when I just show "profile" without referencing the fields in the "User ID" line, I receive the following HTML displayed on the page:

```
Personal photo:

Show profile to others?:

User ID: [ { "personal_photo_url": "bing.jpg", "show_profile": false, "id": 1 } ]
```

It's worth pointing out that when I do some querying all the fields are listed as "undefined", even though they are showing per above.

So my question is pretty simple - how do I get the values from these fields showing without all the JSON formatting?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a bit more trial and error I realised what had happened is that I was sending in an array to the page.

When I adjusted my search result from the database to use the .findOne() method instead of .find() the data was presented as I needed it (ie just one record), and my code above worked perfectly.